# Readline() in Java does not handle Chinese characters properly

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I have a text file with Chinese words written to a line. The line is surrounded with `"\r\n"`, and written using `fileOutputStream.write(string.getBytes())`.

I have no problems reading lines of English words, my buffered reader parses it with `readLine()` perfectly. However, it recognizes the Chinese sentence as multiple lines, thus screwing up my programme flow.

Any solutions?

Comment: It would help with some example input and code.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`string.getBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) encodes the `String` using the platform default encoding. That is rarely what you want, especially when you're trying to write characters that are not native to your current locale.

Specify the encoding instead (using [`string.getBytes("UTF-8")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29), for example).

A cleaner and more Java-esque way would be to wrap your `OutputStream` in an `OutputStreamWriter` like this:

```
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
```

Then you can simply call [`writer.write(string)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29) and don't need to repeat the encoding each time you want to write a `String`.

And, as commented below, specify the same encoding when reading the file (using a `Reader`, preferably).

Comment: ...and of course also specify the encoding when constructing the reader.

Answer (score 2):

If you're outputting the text via `fileOutputStream.write(string.getBytes())`, you're outputting with the *default encoding* for the platform. It's important to ensure you're then reading with the appropriate encoding, and using methods that are encoding-aware. The problem won't be in your `BufferedReader` instance, but whatever `Reader` you have under it that's converting bytes into characters.

This article may be of use: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)